# Auto-indent in RStudio won't go to new line

Tags: r, rstudio

I have looked everywhere on RStudio, here, and googled it.

My auto indent does not seem to work.

I have tried <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> (and several other keys).  The opening curly brace `{` does not seem to matter. Is there some way to restore the auto indent feature?

Comment: Tools -> Global Options -> Code Editing.  But this is not a programming question and is off-topic for SO

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. RStudio is an IDE for R, so I think this is on-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the Tools -> Global Options -> Code Editing suggestion.  I have tried this menu choice, but do not see any selection which is a switch for "indent on", or "indent off".  No other choice seems to address this option.  Can you tell me which box to check to turn on indenting please?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, and solved it as follows:

1. Select all code in the active window
2. From the Code menu, select "Reindent Lines"

Hope this helps.